# Apache Gremlin Updating a Property results into Property Addition Not Supported when updating a vertex

Tags: scala, playframework, gremlin, tinkerpop3

Here is the error that I am encountering.

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[IllegalStateException: Property addition is not supported]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:251)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:178)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:363)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:361)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$recoverWith$1(Future.scala:413)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:37)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Property addition is not supported
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Element$Exceptions.propertyAdditionNotSupported(Element.java:133)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.detached.DetachedVertex.property(DetachedVertex.java:91)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.detached.DetachedVertex.property(DetachedVertex.java:50)
    at gremlin.scala.ScalaElement.$anonfun$updateWith$2(ScalaElement.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:231)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:462)
    at gremlin.scala.ScalaElement.updateWith(ScalaElement.scala:76)
    at gremlin.scala.ScalaElement.updateWith$(ScalaElement.scala:70)
    at gremlin.scala.ScalaVertex.updateWith(ScalaVertex.scala:8)
    at gremlin.scala.ScalaElement.updateAs(ScalaElement.scala:82)
```

Here are my models and the way I have defined it.

```
import java.util. UUID
import gremlin.scala.{Element, Marshallable, Vertex, id, label, underlying}


@label("trip")
case class TripModel(tripId: Option[String] = None,
                     name: String,
                     createdDate: java.time.Instant = java.time.Instant.now(),
                     startDate: java.time.Instant,
                     duration: Int,
                     totalAdults: Int,
                     totalChildrens: Int,
                     @underlying vertex: Option[Vertex] = None
                    )

object TripModel {

  implicit val marshaller = new Marshallable[TripModel] {
    def toCC(element: Element): TripModel = {
      val tripId = Some(element.value[UUID]("tripId").toString)
      val tripName = element.value[String]("name")
      val duration =  element.value[Int]("duration")
      val totalAdults = element.value[Short]("totalAdults")
      val totalChildren =element.value[Short]("totalChildrens")
      val date = element.value[java.time.Instant]("createdDate")
      val startDate = element.value[java.time.Instant]("startDate")

      models.TripModel(tripId = tripId, name = tripName,
        startDate  = startDate, duration = duration,
        totalAdults = totalAdults, totalChildrens = totalChildren, createdDate = date)
    }

    override def fromCC(cc: TripModel): FromCC = {
      val values = Map("name" -> cc.name,
        "createdDate" -> cc.createdDate,
        "startDate" -> cc.startDate,
        "duration"-> cc.duration,
        "totalAdults" -> cc.totalAdults,
        "totalChildrens" -> cc.totalChildrens,
        "tripId" -> UUID.fromString(cc.tripId.get).toString)
      FromCC(None, "trip", values)
    }
  }
}
```

And the way I update a vertex is as follows

```
def updateTripDetails(id:String, tripUpdate: UpdateTripRequest) = {
    implicit val g = db.g

    val item = db.g.V().has(KeyValue(tripId, id)).head
    item.updateAs[TripModel](cc => cc.copy(name = tripUpdate.tripName.getOrElse(cc.name)))
  }
```

What I am trying to do is to update a certain vertex property, however I always received the aforementioned error. is there any workaround for this?

I am connecting to gremlin server. this is how I build the connection.

```
class GrDbConnection @Inject()  (config: Configuration) {

  private val dseCluster = DseCluster.builder()
    .addContactPoints(config.get[String]("dse.cluster.address"))
    .withPort(config.get[Int]("dse.cluster.port"))
    .build()

  private val graphName = "graphName"
  private val graphOptions = new GraphOptions().setGraphName(graphName)
  private val session = dseCluster.connect()

  session.executeGraph(new SimpleGraphStatement("schema.config().option('graph.schema_mode').set('development')").setGraphName(graphName))
  session.executeGraph(new SimpleGraphStatement("schema.config().option('graph.allow_scan').set('true')").setGraphName(graphName))
  // Create a ScalaGraph from a remote Traversal Source using withRemote
  // See: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connecting-via-remotegraph for more details
  private val connection = DseRemoteConnection.builder(session).withGraphOptions(graphOptions).build()
  val g:ScalaGraph = EmptyGraph.instance().asScala
    .configure(_.withRemote(connection))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how you create `g` but I assume you are connecting to a remote graph (e.g. the graph is hosted in Gremlin Server) and not an embedded one so in that case this line:

```
val item = db.g.V().has(KeyValue(tripId, id)).head
```

returns a `DetachedVertex`. It has no knowledge of the graph it is connected to and therefore you can think of it as read-only. You don't update its properties directly, you use Gremlin to do your updates. I don't know how playframework is handling the underlying updates, but I bet it's not expecting the "detached" elements and presumes a local embedded graph instance and thus elements that know about their host graph.

That said, the proper way to update the properties of a vertex is to simply use Gremlin and not directly operate on the `Vertex` object itself and therefore you would prefer updating like this:

```
g.V(item).property('name', 'some name')
```

Comment: on the g.V(item) item would the ID of the object we are trying to update? or is it the vertex? yes it is indeed true that we are connecting to a gremlin server

Comment: "item" can be an vertex identifier or the `Vertex` object itself.